# How does gravity escape from a black hole?

Tags: gravity, black-holes, speed-of-light

Nothing can escape from a black hole except for Hawking radiation.
Nothing can travel faster than the speed of light.
Gravity travels at the speed of light.
How does gravity escape from a black hole ?

Comment: Hawking radiation doesn't 'escape' from a black hole, but this Q has been asked many times here. See:
https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/937/
https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/240302/

Comment: Why do you think or what do you mean by your comment that gravity "escapes" from the black hole. (That's not true, but maybe if you're more clear about what you meant we could explain why you're notion isn't right.)

Comment: *https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/937/how-does-gravity-escape-a-black-hole*